# How to perform a \$\dfrac{1}{s+a}\$ type integration in MATLAB?

Tags: control, control-system, matlab, laplace-transform, integrator

Currently, I am integrating an ODE of the form \$\dot x = f(x,t)\$ in MATLAB using the function **ode45**

This is equivalent (in block diagram form) as passing \$\dot x\$ through an integrator \$\dfrac{1}{s}\$ to obtain \$x\$

[image]

However, now I wish to use an alternate integrator of the form: \$\dfrac{1}{s+a}\$

**What is the best way to achieve this using MATLAB?**

Comment: The diagram you posted makes it look like you're using simulink. If you can use simulink, there are PID controllers (PI and PD) having modifiable parameters, as far as I remember.

Comment: @K.Rmth Yes I am considering simulink as well. However, I'm pretty much using a script + ode45 function at this point, so it would be a big change to rewrite this in simulink. I'm keeping that as a last resort but if there are ways to numerically perform \$\dfrac{1}{s+a}\$ integration via a script rather than simulink then it would be awesome.

Comment: Isnt this better suited for another stackexchange (math or dsp or other). It doesn't involve electrical design at all. Some might argue and say that it is relevant because such equations are used in frequency analysis etc.. But so is basic algebra, y = mx+b, how can i solve for - and we don't see those here.

Comment: 1/s is integrator, while 1/(a+s) is 1st order and the other is second order, they ain't integrators. Now don't mix apples with peaches.

Comment: ode45 , which is a numerical solution, is NOT equivalent to a 1/s integration, which is an exact solution and never calls a numerical integrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert but look at this page: http://ctms.engin.umich.edu/CTMS/index.php?example=Introduction&section=SystemModeling

In the command prompt, you can write as follows:

```
s = tf('s');
integrator = 1/(s+a) ;
```

Then simply use it in your expression.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an incomplete answer, I just want to comment but I don't have enough reputation yet!
What you are doing above is solving for  (1/s)*(dX(s)/ds) =(1/s)*F(X,s)= X(s) assuming appropriate initial values. This when you use in MATLAB ode45, you can directly give the time domain function[dx/dt=f(x,t)] in function_handle as 1/s in time domain is 1.
If you want to use 1/(s+a) instead of 1 you have to use e^(-at).
What I mean is try converting the ODE that you need to solve to time domain then apply ode45. You eventually need to solve something like
dx/dt = (e^at)*f(x,t) ;  this will be your function !
Hope this helps !
Please correct me if I  am wrong.